# Does "on" mean "ready"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, idioms

*Cecilia cut it into small, soft pieces. She piled the chicken onto the sandwiches and then put the sandwiches on the plates.
Andrew Jr. called out, "**Lunch is on**!"*

Comment: ***On*** means ***on offer, available*** in the cited context. Compare a restaurant waiter saying *The soup of the day is **off*** - which you *could* claim is short for "off the menu", but that's not necessarily literally true (it might be *written* "on" the menu that you're holding in your hand while you're being told you can't order it! :)

Comment: Have you found any meanings of "on" in a [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on) that fit the context?

Comment: I haven't found anything, have you?

Answer (score 0):

"Is on" in this context implies lunchtime has arrived/started.It's informal and concise way of announcing the arrival of meal time.

Comment: Someone told me this "I think your text is American (note that using the suffix Jr or Junior after someone's name is most common in the USA), and "lunch is on" is more of an American phraseology for "lunch is ready". "On" is being used more in a sense of "started" or "going ahead".

Comment: Well - is it American? You don't say in your question where you found it. Oxford Languages has as one of its definitions of **on** _(of an event) taking place or being presented._

Comment: Yeah, it's from American chapters.

Comment: A side remark about usage in your “someone told me* comment. Just so you know, on first reading I took it to mean that you had been told before you posted your question. I’d recommend that better than the simple past would be the present perfect *someone has told me*, which more clearly implies that this telling has taken place since you posted. Aren’t English verbs fun?

Comment: Actually I have been told that at the same time because I posted the question on two places. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Chapters of **what book?** Please give the source of passages that you quote.

Comment: American chapters, The storm, Greta Gorsuch